# PHPunit warning error testsuits not expected

Tags: php, phpunit

I am new to working with PHPunit. I installed PHPunit with composer and created a phpunit.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

    <phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" colors="true">
        <testsuits>
            <testsuit name="unit">
                <directory>tests</directory>
            </testsuit>
        </testsuits>
    </phpunit>
```

I get the following error message

PHPUnit 7.5.16 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Warning - The configuration file did not pass validation!
  The following problems have been detected:

Line 4:
  - Element 'testsuits': This element is not expected.

Test results may not be as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo on your file `<testsuites>` and not `<testsuits>` and also for `<testsuite>` instead of `<testsuit>`

see https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/configuration.html#the-testsuites-element

Comment: You and I understand French, but others may not. The link you left should be in English. On top of that, typo questions should be voted / flagged to be closed as such.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to change the language on my link.